# WooCommerce: adding form elements to variable.php breaks quantity functionality

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I added two extra form elements (radio buttons) within the form of `single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php`. Now quantity field doesn't work: if I pick "5" for instance, click `Add-to-Cart` button and visit my Cart, only 1 item was added instead of 5. If I remove my extra elements, it works again. Any suggestion as to what's going on?

I added my form elements right after `do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_variation' );` :

```
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_variation' ); ?>

<div class="auto_replenish_wrap">
    <div class="auto_replenish_option">
        <input type="radio" name="auto_replenish" value="auto_replenish_no" checked="checked">
        <label for="auto_replenish_no">
            Deliver one-time only
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="auto_replenish_option">
        <input type="radio" name="auto_replenish" value="auto_replenish_yes">
        <label for="auto_replenish_yes">
            <div class="auto_replenish_yes_label">
                Auto-replenish <a href='#'>(See details)</a>
            </div>
            <div class="auto_replenish_yes_label_frequency">
                <span class="delivery_frequency">
                    Deliver every
                    <input type="button" class="minus" value="-">
                    <input type="text" size="4" class="input-text qty text" title="Qty" value="1" name="quantity" step="1" pattern="[0-9]*" id="delivery_frequency_value" min="1">
                    <input type="button" class="plus" value="+">
                    month(s)
                </span>
            </div>
        </label>
    </div>          
</div>
<div class="add_to_cart_and_learn_more">
    <a class="learn_more_after_add_to_cart_button" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Learn More</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show your code? Also, from past experience, if you can add the fields to a hook, I always think that's better than overriding the add to cart templates. Have just had to rescue too many broken sites for clients.

Comment: Hey Helga :) I added the code in my question!

Comment: Also I tried to contact you (about something else) through your website but it won't let me send the message, I tried doing so with FF and Chrome.

Comment: The input you have added for `delivery_frequency_value` has the same name as the quantity button, ie: `name="quantity"`. Presumably WooCommerce is pulling the quantity value from your new input and not the expected one.

Comment: Exactly the problem, thanks!